# Trying to identify a science fiction spoof movie about a singing alien

Tags: story-identification, movie

When I was little, in the early 80's, I saw part of a movie that scared the crap out of me, although it was actually a comedy.  It was more or less a spoof of Alien, extremely low budget, and very silly.  The crew of a spaceship encounters an alien cyclops made of red slime.  They connect it to a translator and it sings a song about wanting to eat people.  A doctor assures the others that the alien is harmless, and is immediately devoured by the alien.  The movie ends with the alien being sucked into space and floating along behind the spacecraft.

The movie was ridiculous, but I was about 5 years old at the time, and that red slime monster was the monster under my bed for the next several years.

Comment: Is there a reason [you favorite all of your own questions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A44025+infavorites%3A44025)?

Comment: @Null - Force of habit.  I did it the first time I asked a question, because I didn't know that they would show up in a list on my profile, and I haven't stopped doing it yet.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8870/mark-my-own-question-as-favorite

Comment: I also upvote comments just to show that I have read them.  Again, force of habit.

Comment: @Null - The weird thing is that I have asked 101 questions and answered 102 questions, but this is completely coincidental.  I only noticed it yesterday when I realized that I was up to 100 questions.  It just happened to work out that way.

Comment: http://www.forcesofgeek.com/2014/04/alien-imitators-of-eighties.html

Comment: *Delightful* question! :}

Comment: @Null - Your comment encouraged me to break my habit of favoriting all of my own questions.  Thanks.

Comment: The only singing alien worth anything is Pava Laguna from The Fifth Element and this one - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybXrrTX3LuI

Comment: @Null One reason I might bookmark one of my own questions might be so that i'll be able to find it again if it gets deleted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*[The Creature Wasn't Nice](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082213/)*, also known as *Naked Space* or *[Spaceship](http://www.badmovies.org/movies/spaceship/)*, starring Leslie Nielsen.

Quoting from two of the reviews:

> The initially minuscule organism promptly grows into a large, tubby, one-eyed, red-skinned, slime-dripping man-eating gelatinous humanoid blob which in time-honored hoary B-movie fashion proceeds to devour most of the crew before being jettisoned into space.

....

> As others have mentioned, the creature singing, and dancing is a special, funny treat.

And, video:

Comment: That is the one.  And now everyone on SE knows what the monster under my bed looked like.  Well done!

Comment: ^_^ I recognized it as a movie on Badmovies.org (http://www.badmovies.org/movies/spaceship/) but it took me a search or two to locate it.

Comment: Full disclosure:  I actually knew the name of the movie already.  I just wanted to see how long it would take for someone to find the answer.  You deserve a bounty.  Let's say 200 points.  I will open the bounty in 2 days.

Comment: It isn't a bad movie.  It is an epically horrible movie.  It took me over 20 years to find it, because it is so obscure that no one ever saw it.  I finally managed to get a bootleg DVD of it and watched it.  Then I hated the 5 year old me for being afraid of something so ridiculous.  It was so bad that they were able to rerelease it with a new title - Naked Space- after Leslie Nielsen's Naked Gun series came out (he's in this movie too).

Comment: No worries. FWIW, the boogieman of my childhood was the banshee from *Darby O'Gill and the Little People*.

Comment: Oops- I just noticed that you added the alternate title before I made the comment about it.  You're really good.

Comment: @WadCheber :-P I'm not hurting for reputation, but just reminding you that you wanted to approve this one after the bounty.

Comment: Right you are.  Forgot to open the bounty last night.

Comment: Wow, Leslie Nielson and Patrick McNee - got to watch this now!

Comment: @Eborbob - If you really want to, I won't try to stop you.  But when you realize that you'll never get that 90 minutes back, don't blame me.  It is truly horrible.

Comment: @WadCheber :) Point taken!

Comment: @SeanDuggan - Whoever said that the monster singing and dancing is "a special, funny treat" is a f***ing liar.  Nothing about this movie is "funny", and it is only "special" insofar as it is especially awful.  People who enjoy this movie should not be allowed to reproduce.

Comment: I think that's a little harsh @WadCheber, I'm sure that anyone who sat through the film would look back and consider the singing monster the highlight of the film!

Comment: I was joking.  And I can award the bounty in 11 hours.

Comment: Dammit! That's gonna eat up the next 1h17minutes of my life!